# Does images have to be power of two in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, resolution

I'm creating an Android app with a map using the *Google Maps API v2*. I'm creating custom markers for it, and I wonder if the images for them (the markers) **has** to "be power of two" (has a resolution which where both the width and the height is the same, and power of two), or if I can use whatever resolution I like?

In many cases I've seen, power of two is required, and I wonder if this is one of those cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map marker can have any size you want. This is the case you want to provide correctly scaled bitmaps to your `drawable` folders.

Comment: Thanks! So, just to make sure I've understood it right: I should use power of two images for icons, but for everything else, I can use whatever size?

Comment: The only case i can think of is that you need 512x512 image for google play. All other images can have any size. Where did you get the idea?

Comment: I've seen so many cases which requires power of two images, and the examples on the google developers page has power of two images for icons, so I thought it was the same in this case. Thanks!